# Extract CSS Styles from HTML using JSOUP in JAVA

Tags: java, jsoup

Can anyone help with extraction of CSS styles from HTML using Jsoup in Java.
For e.g in below html i want to extract **.ft00 and .ft01**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Page 1</TITLE>

<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<DIV style="position:relative;width:931;height:1243;">
<STYLE type="text/css">
<!--
    .ft00{font-size:11px;font-family:Times;color:#ffffff;}
    .ft01{font-size:11px;font-family:Times;color:#ffffff;}
-->
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the style is embedded in your Element you just have to use `.attr("style")`.

JSoup is not a Html renderer, it is just a HTML parser, so you will have to parse the content from the retrieved `<style>` tag html content. You can use a simple regex for this; but it won't work in all cases. You may want to use a CSS parser for this task.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String html = "<HTML>\n" +
                "<HEAD>\n"+
                "<TITLE>Page 1</TITLE>\n"+
                "<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n"+
                "<DIV style=\"position:relative;width:931;height:1243;\">\n"+
                "<STYLE type=\"text/css\">\n"+
                "<!--\n"+
                "    .ft00{font-size:11px;font-family:Times;color:#ffffff;}\n"+
                "    .ft01{font-size:11px;font-family:Times;color:#ffffff;}\n"+
                "-->\n"+
                "</STYLE>\n"+
                "</HEAD>\n"+
                "</HTML>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element style = doc.select("style").first();
        Matcher cssMatcher = Pattern.compile("[.](\\w+)\\s*[{]([^}]+)[}]").matcher(style.html());
        while (cssMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Style `" + cssMatcher.group(1) + "`: " + cssMatcher.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Will output:

```
Style `ft00`: font-size:11px;font-family:Times;color:#ffffff;
Style `ft01`: font-size:11px;font-family:Times;color:#ffffff;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
String style = document.select("style").first().data();
```

You can then use a CSS parser to fetch the details you are interested in.

- http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/SAC
- http://cssparser.sourceforge.net
- https://github.com/corgrath/osbcp-css-parser#readme