# How to get font size and font name from Html using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have tried below code but its not work

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
 Elements elements=doc.select("style");
 for(Element element:elements){
  if(e.contains("font-family")){
   }

 }
```

Comment: jsoup (an HTML parser) will only get the contents of the <style> tag, you will have to use a CSS parser to parse the rules inside it. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13158705/97160